# RestKit EntityMapping with nested array

Tags: ios, json, core-data, restkit

I have a problem with entity mapping part of my JSON response.

I've tried to make a seperate entity for Ingredients in my Core Data model and set the mappingForEntityName to @"Ingredients", but to no avail. In my Dish Core Data entity model I have declared the @"ingredientValue", @"ingredientName", and so on, but when looking in my .sqlite file, it doesn't populate the fields for ingredients.

RestKit doesn't throw any errors back at me. So I'm suspecting it has something to do with the ingredients being stored in an array?

As you can see I've declared 2 RKEntityMapping instances (I don't know if this is the correct way of doing it?). But my ingredients are not returned.

The JSON looks like this:

```
{ dishes: [
 {
    id: 34,
    name: "Pavlova med citroncreme og jordbær",
    header: "En laekker marengs kage til enhver lejlighed",
    howto: "lots of text....",
    image: "/img_path/img.jpg",
    created_at: "2014-04-05T00:25:22.378Z",
    ingredients: [
                    {
                       ingredient_id: 27,
                       ingredient_amount: 3,
                       ingredient_unit: "stk",
                       ingredient_name: "æggehvider"
                     },
                     {
                       ingredient_id: 28,
                       ingredient_amount: 2,
                       ingredient_unit: "dl",
                       ingredient_name: "sukker"
                     }
                 ]
    }
]}
```

Dish.h:

```
@interface Dish : NSManagedObject


@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *dishName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *dishHeader;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *dishImage;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *dishIngredients;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger dishID;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSData *dishMainText;
@property (nonatomic) NSDate *createdAt;

//Ingredients
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *ingredientName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *ingredientUnit;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger ingredientValue;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger ingredientID;
@end
```

Dish.m:

```
RKEntityMapping *dishMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Dish" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    [dishMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                    @"id":          @"dishID",
                                                    @"name":        @"dishName",
                                                    @"header":      @"dishHeader",
                                                    @"howto":       @"dishMainText",
                                                    @"image":       @"dishImage",
                                                    @"created_at":   @"createdAt"}];


    dishMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"dishID" ];

    RKEntityMapping *ingredientMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Dish" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    [ingredientMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                    @"ingredient_amount": @"ingredientValue",
                                                    @"ingredient_unit": @"ingredientUnit",
                                                    @"ingredient_name": @"ingredientName"}];

    [dishMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"dishes" toKeyPath:@"dishes" withMapping:ingredientMapping]];


    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:dishMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                       pathPattern:@"/dishes.json"
                                                                                           keyPath:@"dishes"
                                                                                       statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

**EDIT** Added part of the log output for `RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace)`

```
with mapping <RKEntityMapping:0x8f69750 objectClass=NSManagedObject propertyMappings=(
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8f6c150 name => dishName>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8f6c190 id => dishID>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8f6c480 header => dishHeader>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8f6c4a0 howto => dishMainText>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8f6c520 image => dishImage>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8f6c5c0 created_at => createdAt>",
    "<RKRelationshipMapping: 0x8f6d8e0 dishes => dishes>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see `dishes` defined in your `Dish` entity. It should be a to-many relationship to `Ingredient`.

`ingredientMapping` should use the `Ingredient` entity.

Where you call `dishMapping addPropertyMapping:...`, you should be using `...FromKeyPath:@"ingredients" ...` to match the key name in the JSON coming in.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm new to RestKit and the whole entityMapping thing. But why would I define dishes in my entity? I thought that I only needed to specify the items I needed to pull out of my dishes objects in my JSON feed?

Comment: And for some reason, when I change the entity to `Ingredients` for `ingredientMapping`, I get the following error `the entity Dish is not key value coding-compliant for the key "dishes".'` I suppose that might be connected to what you said about defining `dishes` in the Dish entity?

Comment: You're using `addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping` so you need to have a relationship corresponding to that in the data model (and thus in your managed object subclass)

Comment: Yes, that is connected. You need to fix all of the items listed (and possibly some other things that I can't currently tall are wrong ;-) )

Comment: My word... It worked. Although an explanation as to why would be wonderful :) I added `dishes` as a string value to my Dish entity, and the `ingredients` entity is now properly populated. But I must admit I don't really understand what's going on properly. Could you elaborate? How would I tie the has_many relationship together for the two entities? Thanks for your help so far - Chris

Comment: `dishes` as a string? So you have also changed / added a relationship called `ingredients` to the `Dish` entity?

Comment: Should it be an int value that would then store the ID of the dish? So, if I understand you correctly, I should add a `dishes` key to my `Ingredients` entity, and vice versa?

Comment: Wait. Think about only 1 thing at a time - the relationship. What do you have for that? Any id / name information is separate to the relationship (because your data is nested in the JSON).

Comment: Hmm, do you mean the id that ties the two models together? I.e. the ID value stored in the join table on the server?

Comment: Don't think in terms of tables. Core Data is an object store (even if it happens to be backed by SQLite) - there are no tables as far as we're concerned. You don't need ids for linking, you should hold them only for unique identification. In the Core Data model you should have a relationship between the entities.

Comment: I think I see what you mean now. So I would set up a relationship in my CoreData model where Dish has a relationship to Ingredients?

Comment: Yes, exactly, and the name of that relationship is used when you create the `RKRelationshipMapping` as the `to` key path.

Comment: (Sorry for not taking this to the chat btw, but don't have enough rep). One last question then. How do I then call the ingredient associated with my dish? Is that done through the fetchedResultsController? Thanks so much for you help :)

Comment: You can use the relationship directly (be sure to regenerate your managed object subclasses after you make changes). Or, you can use an FRC with a fetch request which has a predicate to filter based on the relationship contents (generally a better approach).

Comment: Ok, I will have to read up on all that. Thanks for your help Wain. I really appreciate it! - Chris